# Is it possible to have one content section overlap another in Experience Cloud Builder?

Tags: header, lwr, builder, experience

By default, there are three sections that come with the LWR site template.
Header - Content - Footer.
I am doing a simple landing page for a convention that has a quiz. There is no need for me to have the header and the footer.
Is there a way to remove them at all? The norm is that it is unable to be deleted - unless I am not seeing something.
I have also tried to have the content section overlap the header section with positioning the section to top and left = 0. This does not work. It only pertains to the component section itself.

---

I have just edited the head markup - header and footer to display: none. Not sure if this is best practices? I am not too sure as to how to import a css stylesheet that will affect the entire site. I presume static resources, will research some more.